# Selected text disappears after page div element update

Tags: php, html, ajax, chat, refresh

I have created a chat page. Problem is when I select chat text and chat refreshes, the selected text disappears. I know there are chats that keep selected text even if the page refreshes. I want to keep text selected after updating text. My page has `div` element and it updates its content from `chatLog.txt` file. Any hints how to make it work?

```js
$(function worker(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        complete: function() {

          setTimeout(worker, 3000);

        }
    });
     $("#divBox").load("chatLog.txt");
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is normal, if you refresh (re-mount) a part of the DOM, the selected text will disappear. If you want to maintain the selected text, you should try React, Vue or Angular, because these handle virtual DOM, these technologies does easy make a chat app and no re-mount the DOM every moment. 
Not use Ajax, you should work with websockets, use socket.io or Laravel Websocket, or similar.

Try :)